# How to fetch whether a USB device is connected to USB3.0 or USB2.0 port

Tags: java, linux, windows, usb

I just want to know how to find a usb device is connected to USB3.0 or USB2.0 port in windows as well as linux. FYI,  I am using libusbK in WINDOWS and in libusb in LINUX is used to access usb device. Is there any api's or any techniques available to fetch the said information?

Eg: If a usb device is connected to USB3.0, i should be able to tell the user that usb device is connected to USB3.0 port.

Is it not possible to fetch the USB details as mentioned above?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: have you looked if libusb provides that ? It probably does...

Answer (score 1):

The USB Specification Number which device complies is encoded in the field `bcdUSB` of the device descriptor.

In `libusb` you got that information on the struct [libusb_device_descriptor](http://libusb.sourceforge.net/api-1.0/structlibusb__device__descriptor.html)

In `libUSBK` you gat that in the struct [USB_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR](http://libusbk.sourceforge.net/UsbK3/struct_u_s_b___d_e_v_i_c_e___d_e_s_c_r_i_p_t_o_r.html)

It should be easy to access them :)

Comment: Thank you, I tried once, the bcdUSB in libUSBK returns 0x200 when I plugin my USB device in both USB2.0 and USB3.0. What shall I do?

Comment: perencia : I didnt get the solution as expected!!! is there any other way to get these details?